# MVC3 and SSRS reportviewer interactivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, reporting-services

I've been trying to integrate SSRS reportviewer to my MVC application.  I have followed several tutorials about how to set up the datasource and designing the report.  However, I'm trying to run it in `LocalReport` mode and I am having issues with the interactivity.  If I try to sort a column I get errors.

If I try it this way:

```
<form id="RosterControl" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer" runat="server" AsyncRendering="true" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractivityPostBackMode="AlwaysAsynchronous" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="980px">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\Roster.rdlc" >
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource  DataSourceId="RosterDataSource" Name="Roster" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="RosterDataSource" runat="server" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetData" 
    TypeName="VirtualCare.Web.CbsDataSetTableAdapters.PatientTableAdapter">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Then I get this error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed
```

If I try it by changing `AsyncRendering="true"` and `InteractivityPostBackMode="AlwaysSynchronous"`

Then the entire page reloads and the data is unchanged.

In my view I call the ascx by using Razor

```
@Html.Partial("RosterControl")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.